# MySQL query missing data

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to query data from 3 MySQL tables in 1 database, filtered by fixed street name (Lucas st.), phone type (home/office/mobile) and address type (home/office). Also have to include rows with missing data (ex. someone has no mobile phone, still have to query that). Since FULL JOIN is not supported in MySQL, I tried JOIN and UNION ALL, but no result so far.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, street, building, apartment, phone_number  
FROM person  
JOIN phone ON person.id = phone.person_id  
JOIN address ON phone.person_id = address.person_id WHERE address.street='Lucas st.' AND phone.type='home' AND address.type='home';
```

Any tips and ideas would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT first_name, last_name, street, building, apartment, phone_number  
FROM person  
LEFT JOIN phone   ON person.id = phone.person_id  
                 AND phone.type='home'
LEFT JOIN address ON phone.person_id = address.person_id 
                 AND address.street='Lucas st.'  
                 AND address.type='home';
```